How to Recreate Redo Log Files During Database Restore?
is it possible to recreate the redo log files during the database restore?
I used the following command:
run{
ALLOCATE CHANNEL c1 DEVICE TYPE disk;
set newname for database to '+DATA';
RESTORE DATABASE;
switch datafile all;
recover database;
}

It created the data files that were in the Linux mount point inside the diskgroup, but it did not recreate the redo logs within +DATA. They were restored in the Linux mount point (as per the controlfile from the old environment), so I had to recreate them manually inside the diskgroup.
Note: I also changed the following parameters before the restore.
SQL> show parameters online

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_create_online_log_dest_1          string      +DATA
db_create_online_log_dest_2          string      +FRA

